# Unable to import org.apache.common.collections.list

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using Groovy Grails Tool Suite for my Grails project.
I am trying to use LazyList.decorate in one of my domain classes and so want to import org.apache.common.collections.list within the domain class.
I see that org.apache.commons.collections_3.2.0.v2013030210310.jar is available under the GGTS plugins folder.
However, the editor shows an error at the import statement saying "Groovy: Unable to resolve org.apache.common.collections.list".
Please help!

Comment: grails itself uses common-collections so importing LazyList should work out of the box (it does for me with grails 2.4.3). That GGTS uses commons-collections has no influence on grails.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is missing a code snippet I suspect you have a line like this `import org.apache.common.collections.list`. You should do `import org.apache.common.collections.list.*` - or if only LazyList is what you want: `import org.apache.common.collections.list.LazyList`

Comment: I think I spoke a little too early. When I import org.apache.commons.collections.list.*, the error in editor disappears. However LazyList.decorate() is unrecognized in editor. No error when I run the application but doesn't save my child class either.
Next, I tried to import org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList, the editor shows this statement as an error
"unable to resolve org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList"
I tried to add plugins/org.apache.commons.collections_3.2.0...jar to project buildpath but still same error
I am using GGTS 3.6 IDE
Please help!